# Command 'pm2' not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

I recently cloned my nodejs express app on ec2 ubuntu instance. I ran `npm install pm2` but it didn't have write permissions. So I ran

```
sudo chown _R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules
```

After that PM2 got installed but when I hit `pm2 start app.js`, it shows pm2 command not found. I have installed it globally locally but nothing works.
What should I do? Check out the [screenshot of ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnrmg.png)

Answer (score 7):

`pm2` needs to be installed globally (on the server) to function correctly.

Try

```
sudo npm install -g pm2
```

Digital Ocean has an [excellent tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your home directory

   sudo npm install -g pm2
2. relogin to OR restart your instance

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple way to solve it, just add the pm2 statement as a new script in your package.json file.

**In your root project folder type**

```
nano package.json
```

**Then the package file opens and you can add the following line after the script line**

```
"pm2 start src/<yourappname.js>"
```

**your file should look like this**

```
"scripts": {
    "pm2": "pm2 starts src/<yourappname.js>"
  }
```

**Then press ctl + x and enter to save**

*(You ust replace src/<yourappname.js> for the path adn name of your js file, in my case I have a folder called src into my project root folder)*

**Lastly, just run the script by typing the following line**

```
npm run pm2
```

and you got it.